# Is it possible to export html form data into an Excel template?

Tags: php, html, excel

I have an html page that has a form for the user to fill out after conducting a list of tests.

Once they are done filling out the form they submit and it is entered into a database table.

Is it possible to have this information also exported into an excel file with a predefined template (containing charts, and graphs) that would be downloaded onto the user's computer upon submit?

Comment: Just the information exported into Excel? Sure, it's possible.

Comment: Create an Excel with all the data you want (sample data for example) and save it as XML. Open it in a text editor (gedit or Notepad ++ for example). So looking at it you can create your own excel file working to XMLs parse tools.

Comment: Plenty of libraries for handling Excel files in PHP: I'd recommend [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net), though I am slightly biased

Comment: So my main goal is to have the data thrown into an excel template I have created with cells for all of the data. I tried to take your advice Jonathas, however viewing .xls files in an editor only works when the contents are in plain text. This does not work for .xls files with tables, graphs, and charts. Mark, thanks for the suggestion, I will definitely check it out.

Comment: Caveat with PHPExcel - charts are only supported for OfficeOpenXML (xlsx) format, not for BIFF (xls) yet